# Installing R version 3.6.3 in Ubuntu 18.04 - "make" problem

Tags: 18.04, r

I have already uninstalled the old R version and i'm trying to reinstall (My OS is Ubuntu 18.04). I am using these commands:

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf R-3.6.3.tar.gz
cd R-3.6.3
./configure --enable-R-shlib
```

After that, I'm trying to use these ones:

```
make
sudo make install
```

However, when I type make, I got the following message:

```
make: *** No target indicated and no make file found. Stop.
```

How can I deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indicates that there is no makefile in that directory.  Try changing the line `./configure --enable-R-shlib` to `./configure --enable-R-shlib=yes`, or running just `./configure`.  If this doesn't work, try this:

Install the packages necessary to add a new repository over HTTPS:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https software-properties-common
```

Enable the CRAN repository and add the CRAN GPG key to your system:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
```

Update the packages list, and install the R package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Run `R --version` to check that the installation was successful.  Hope all this helps you,

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me!

Comment: You are very welcome.